# Toggle function to single element using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle

Please, tell me how to apply the toggle function to one element and not to all. This function adds a class to all elements where use a "modal" state.

On image here what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
    state = {
        isLoading: true,
        table: [],
        photos: [],
        error: null,
        modal: true
    };

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({ modal: !state.modal}))
    };

    fetchUsers() {
        fetch(`${API_URL}/post/`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>
                this.setState({
                    table: data.results,
                    photos: data.results.photos,
                    isLoading: false,
                })
            )
            .catch(error => this.setState({error, isLoading: false}));
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchUsers();
    }

        const {isLoading, table, error, modal} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="news-container">
                    <div className="container">
                        {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
                        {!isLoading ? (
                            table.map(result => {
                                const {id, title, created_date, text, author, photos} = result;
                                const img = [];
                                for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
                                    img.push(<img src={photos[i]} alt=""/>);
                                }
                                return (
                                    <div className={modal ? "news-card" : "news-card news-card-open"} key={id}>
                                        <p className="title">{title}</p>
                                        <span className="news-date">{created_date}</span>
                                        <div className="describe-block">
                                            <pre>Describe: {text}</pre>
                                            <p>{author}</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <button className={modal ? "" : "open"} id={id} onClick={this.handleClick}>Expand</button>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })
                        ) : (
                            <h3>Loading...</h3>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Babak Yaghoobi, but i used the data id sent from the backend. And it's work allmost. New small problem, when click to another "expand" first click will be removed class open on before element and than when second click add new class to current element

```
...
 state = {
        isLoading: true,
        table: [],
        photos: [],
        error: null,
        modal: true,
        modalIndex: -1
    };

    handleClick = (id) => {
        this.setState(state => ({ modal: !state.modal, modalIndex: id}))
    };
...
<button className={modal && modalIndex === id ? "" : "open"} id={id} onClick={()=>this.handleClick(result.id)}>Expand</button>
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    state = {
        isLoading: true,
        table: [],
        photos: [],
        error: null,
        modal: true,
        modalIndex: -1
    };

    handleClick = (index) => {
        this.setState(state => ({ modal: !state.modal, modalIndex: index}))
    };

    fetchUsers() {
        fetch(`${API_URL}/post/`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>
                this.setState({
                    table: data.results,
                    photos: data.results.photos,
                    isLoading: false,
                })
            )
            .catch(error => this.setState({error, isLoading: false}));
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchUsers();
    }
    const {isLoading, table, error, modal, modalIndex} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="news-container">
                <div className="container">
                    {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
                    {!isLoading ? (
                        table.map((result, index) => {
                            const {id, title, created_date, text, author, photos} = result;
                            const img = [];
                            for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
                                img.push(<img src={photos[i]} alt=""/>);
                            }
                            return (
                                <div className={modal && modalIndex == index ? "news-card" : "news-card news-card-open"} key={id}>
                                    <p className="title">{title}</p>
                                    <span className="news-date">{created_date}</span>
                                    <div className="describe-block">
                                        <pre>Describe: {text}</pre>
                                        <p>{author}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <button className={modal && modalIndex == index ? "" : "open"} id={id} onClick={()=>this.handleClick(index)}>Expand</button>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })
                    ) : (
                        <h3>Loading...</h3>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you describe how your answer solves the problem?

Comment: I added just index for handleClick(index) and check it with modal when render after setState with className={modal && modalIndex == index ? "" : "open"}

Comment: vote is not important, that's important your problem solving